# Calculating the amount of data (bytes) a user using

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

We are a subscription based platform that charges per data used. How do we calculate the total amount of data used by 'get' and 'post' requests by a user? Also, how can we calculate the HTTP request size? 
As we are using AWS does AWS have some mechanism or service to calculate our user data usage for us?

Comment: did you [tag your aws resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-resources-for-billing)? it may help you check your costs from their [billing console and cost management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/configurecostallocreport.html). It may require some setting up though if that is what you want

Comment: Does your HTTP service create logfiles? Parse them for actual data transfer. You will need to map their IP address to an account.

Comment: An answer to this question will require (at least) a clearer definition of "user."  In many (most?) web applications, a "user" (end user, site user) is not an entity of which the AWS infrastructure (or any other cloud provider) is (or would be) aware.  Additionally, what resources the user is directly connecting to (EC2?) and what is running there to directly handle the requests (Nginx?).